# Bash script generating image from video with specific title in subdirs

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have the following bash script generating a jpg file with the same name of the video file. Now I need to change the bash script to generate the jpg file with the name image.jpg instead of with the same name of the video.

I tried lots of different ways to do that but I'm not really good in bash scripting and I have some problem with the basename and subdirectories.

May you please help me?

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in */*.mp4; do 
j=`basename $i .mp4`; 
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -r 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 640x360 -ss 0:0:30 $j.jpg;
done
```

Following the directory tree

```
/
/a/video1.mp4
/b/video2.mp4
/c/video3.mp4
```

Following the result I need

```
/
/a/video1.mp4
/a/image.jpg
/b/video2.mp4
/b/image.jp4
/c/video3.mp4
/c/image.jpg
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with `for i in */*.mp4`: you can't loop over files in subdirectories like this (try it: `for i in */*.mp4; do echo $i; done` , this only prints `*/*.mp4`).

For a case like this, there's no way around `find`.

One liner solution with `find`:

```
find /your/base/directory -type f -iname "*.mp4" -execdir /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "{}" -r 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 640x360 -ss 0:0:30 image.jpg \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `j` to the desired name

```
j=image
```

instead of setting it to the video's basename.

Comment: not working. It doesn't create the image in the subdirectory but in the / directory

Answer (score 0):

Change code of your bash ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in */*.mp4; do 
DIR=$(dirname ${i})
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$i" -r 1 -f image2 -vframes 1 -s 640x360 -ss 0:0:30 $DIR/image.jpg;
done
```

need explanation read:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6121114

Comment: dirname and basename are the tools you're looking for extracting path components: